# Issue with object data type not being recognised in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code where I want to pass data to an if block with 2 different types that are tackled in if block how to make type script know that the (selected object) is customary and in the other scenario custom plane since I am passing 2 different types and I don't want to do 2 different actionGuard functions but one that can handle both cases at once, in other words, the selected object is erroring out in the if condition saying that selected could be this or this a both are different in keys and values and without having to use casting.

```js
import { CustomCar } from '../app/carSlice';
import { CustomPlane } from '../app/planeSlice';


export const actionGuard = (
  selected: CustomCar | CustomPlane 
  check: CustomCar[] | CustomPlane[] 
  term: string,
  dispatch: any,
  SetSnackBarMsg: any,
  action: string
) => {
  if (term === 'CustomCar' ) {
    if (array.includes((selected as CustomCar){
     // some logic 
    }
   
    if (term === 'CustomPlane') {
    if (array.includes((selected as CustomPlane ){
    // some logic 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can assert that the value being passed into `.includes` is the same type as the array item - as you're doing - you could also assert that the array itself is `unknown[]`, so that you can pass anything into its `.includes`.

```
if ((array as unknown[]).includes((selected){
  // some logic 
}
```

Unfortunately, *some* sort of type assertion (with `as`) is required, due to [an odd TypeScript design decision](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) with `.includes`.

Comment: So some times there is no escape from assertion.

Comment: *Usually* you can avoid assertions when functions are typed well. Still, `.includes` isn't typed well IMO (see that linked github thread).